# The Range of a Function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions

I would like to see minimum and maximum for this example!

```
 g[x_]:=(3 a - 2)/((2 + 3 b - 3 a) x^2) + f*x^(-3 a + 3 b + 2)
```

also for those parameters "1 < a < 2" and "0.6 < b < 0.7"

```
     Minimize[(3 a - 2)/((2 + 3 b - 3 a) x^2) + f*x^(-3 a + 3 b + 2),x] // Simplify
     Reduce[y == -((3 a - 2)/(2 + 3 b - 3 a)) *x^(3 a - 3 b), y, {x}, Reals % // Simplify
```

Comment: Also I used this "FunctionRange" it is not working.

Comment: if we just consider that f is a positive number, could we get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
Minimize[{(3 a - 2)/((2 + 3 b - 3 a) x^2) + f*x^(-3 a + 3 b + 2),1 < a < 2 , 
6/10 < b < 7/10,f>0},{f,a,b,x}]
Maximize[{(3 a - 2)/((2 + 3 b - 3 a) x^2) + f*x^(-3 a + 3 b + 2),1 < a < 2 , 
6/10 < b < 7/10,f>0},{f,a,b,x}]
```

[image]